# giving promotion to make people happy

Tags: people-management

Few small teams report to me, most of the people are happy but a single team who report to me is not happy, as one guy in that team influencing other team mates. he is bit smart and his collegues listens to him. I had a chat with my higher up and he is suggesting to give them promotion to keep them happy so that they will not look out. As a manager is this right approach or any other suggestion.

Comment: It is not clear, whether you are promoting that single person or the whole team ?

Comment: to whole team, as they also not got promotion since quite some time, but in that team only 1 person is quite good, other 3 are average.

Comment: First of all you need to identify why that person is not happy? may be there could be another reason..

Comment: One of the reason i identify after number of discussion with him, that due to promotion, also he does not want to take up more tasks and wanted to work for stipulated hours. He influenced his collegues and provoking them to look out. I dont want resources to quit.

Comment: that's perfect then you can give promotion to him and also if possible then set some fix hours for him.

Comment: What is your company's normal procedure/requirements for promotion?

Comment: performance based and during yearend appraisal (December), but there are exceptions like this one (if happens)

Comment: How do I get a job there? I'm good at complaining, I should be CEO in no time! ;-)

Comment: You have a toxic person who is influencing others to be unhappy? I would be delighted if that person left insted of promoting him.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean a pay raise / rise, rather than promotion?  A change in title without a change in assignments is not really a promotion.

Comment: Perhaps it is just my experience, but you don't get promotions because you have been doing good or average or whatever and then keep doing what you always do. You get promotions because you are able to fulfill the expectations of the position you are being promoted to. Either the people on this team fulfill the requirements for the next higher position or they don't. Even if they are performing average, if they fulfill the requirements for the next higher position then they either should be promoted or be assigned the duties for the next higher position to prove they are deserving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your manager is wrong, you do not ever want to give promotions just because someone is compaining. THat will not help retention.

You seem to be equating promtions to pay raisses as well which is incorrect. While a promotion shoudl involve a pay raise, it certainly is not necessary in order to get a pay raise.

A promotion ALWAYS includes a different level of duties. A senior dev does not do the same things as a junior dev. Therefore if you do not need those extra duties done, then you do not promote (you could increase salary however).

If the person has taken on the duties of the higher position already or if the person has been determined to be capable of doing those duties and you need somoen to do them, then yes you can promote.  But no one should be a senior who is not operating at the senior level espcially not if they are unhappy. A senior can do much more damage than a junior, so promoting a disgruntled person is not wise. People rarely stop being disgrunted just from a promotion.

Considering promoting an entire team is just silly. If you don't need 4 senior people (which you almost never do), then making 4 of them senior is a waste of money. It is bad for the organization budget. Each level of an organzation has progessively fewer people, you don't want everyone to be senior. Then who will do the junior tasks?

Then you have a toxic person who is fairly good at his duties but who is strewing discontent among his team mates. This is person you want to get rid of not a person you want to promote. You can feel as if you need a promotion and are as qualifed as the last person who got one and you can be right. But there still needs to be a position needed to be promoted into. (I can think of at least 5 people who could be senior where I work but there is only one slot. You can't promote everyone who deserves it either. That is just the nature of organizations.)

But when you start taking that unhappinees and making an effort to make sure everyone around you is also unhappy, then you need to be gone. If you want a promotion and talk to the manager and make your case for why you should get one then that's fine. Telling everyone else around you how unfair teh palce is becasue you don't have what you want is not. Encouraging others to look elsewhere is definitely not. Everyone is replaceable and this person is one you should be happy to see the last of. He is not someone you want to reward. That sends the wrong message to the rest of your staff.

If you promote a team with there being no basis for that promotion other than they want it, then you will make every other person on every other team angry that they did not get promoted. Some of them will come to you and say, "I am a better performer than..., why can't I also be promoted?" If you want a quick way to destroy morale, promote the complaining team.

Then, there apears to be no effort to find out the actual concerns of the employees. Money does not solve all or even most issues of discontent. Promotions in name only don't solve anything. You need to find out what is genuinely wrong. Perhaps they are mad becasue your thoughtless boss promoted someone else who was complaining that did not deserve it. Perhaps there are work conditons that can be changed? Perhaps they are tired of daily overtime and on an on.

You never try to fix any problem until you know what the problem actually is. Does your team write code that way? "Hey the users are complaining that things don't work right." "Oh ok, I'll make some random changes until they are satisfied." Of course you wouldn't do that, but that is exactly the same thing you are planning to do by promoting people just because they are unhappy about something.

Answer (score 5):

You have to consider the wider picture. If you promote one individual or team because they are discontent, *unless there is justifiable reason for that promotion* you are storing up trouble for the future. Promotion should reflect the value the individual brings to the business and what they are competent to do, not how well they play the political game. It could be that the individual in question actually deserves a promotion to put him on a level with others who have the same responsibilities and skills - that is, he was overlooked in the past - in which case you would be doing the right thing now. However, it reads as though you're simply trying to prevent him leaving. In which case consider:

- He may be going to leave anyway
- He may be discontented for some reason that the promotion doesn't fix - so you keep him but he remains spreading discontent
- He may be simply trying to squeeze a better deal out of you, and may continue to do so post-promotion
- Others may perceive him being promoted because he's blackmailing you. They may well become discontented and/or do the same

People leave businesses, that is simple reality. The right thing to do may be to not stand in his way, but identify a good potential successor.

Comment: Thanks Julia for brief. Recently one good resource left, and after that i am in a bit pressure to retain. I am 100% agree what you said, but if i promote  only the deserved one there is a possibility other few may left or get demotivated or play more politics. I wanted to to get things going till we get good replacement. My boss suggesting for team promotion.

Answer (score 5):

Your manager is giving you advice on how to keep people happy, without even knowing what it is that this team is unhappy about? We get to learn something new on this site every day.

Did you yourself poll the team and ask what the team is unhappy about? Do you have any idea what the team is unhappy about? And then, you ask us if a team-wide promotion will work.

Worst case scenario:

1. You have no idea what the team is unhappy about.
2. Your pet idea does not work, because it is not a remedy that addresses the root cause of their unhappiness.
3. The other teams get infuriated with you, because you are giving something to that team that you are not giving the other teams.  At this point, nobody is happy with you: the team, the other teams, and your boss. And you're probably not happy with yourself either.

Go back to square one. Do your homework, find out what's wrong before you even think of corrective action.